# Elasticseach script_score get value from a different index

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use script_score to adjust the scoring of a particular result based on the ID value. It works with a basic run. I do not understand how to perform a lookup for the multiplication factor based on a different table. For example I have a MySQL table of ID's and their associated scaling factors. These factors change hourly so they need to be used at query time rather than indexing time. While this table is in MySQL I can put it into an index but how can I do a lookup. I guess it would be similar to a join in MySQL? Below is an idea of what I'm going for:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "params": {
              "param1": 2,
              "param2": 3.1
            },
            "script": "_score * doc['ID'].value in associated table" //Get the scaling factor of the ID from external table/index
          }
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
  },
  "explain": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue. What I had to do was break this down into 2 queries. The first query to the ES index or database table to get the boost factors I required, and then the second query was the main search query to ES. However, whilst constructing the query I built a portion of it dynamically with the data from the first query, thus setting the boost factor as a variable from the data you'd pulled out in the first query. It seems to work quite well for me and hasn't slowed down the search process that much really.

A very cut-down example of this is as follows:

```
$searchParams['index']  = 'someindex';
$searchParams['type']   = 'sometype';
$searchParams['body']['min_score'] = 0.75;
$searchParams['body']['query']['function_score'] = array(
    "query" => array(
        "term" => array("someField"=>$query)
    )
);

foreach($boostFactors as $id=>$factor) {
    $searchParams['body']['query']['function_score']['functions'][] = array(
        "filter" => array(
            "term" => array(
                "id" => $id
            )
        ),
        "script_score" => array("script" => $factor)
    );
}
```